# Rolling sum within 30 non-datetime days

Tags: python, pandas

I've been racking my brain trying to figure out the best way to do this. I want to find the rolling sum of the previous 30 days but my 'day' column is not in datetime format.

Sample data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'client': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 
                   'day': [319, 323, 336, 352, 379, 424, 461, 486, 496, 499, 303, 334, 346, 373, 374, 395, 401, 408, 458, 492],
                   'foo': [5.0, 2.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 7.0, np.nan, np.nan, 8.0, 7.0, 22.0, np.nan, 13.0, np.nan, np.nan, 5.0, 11.0, np.nan]}

>>> df
   client  day   foo
0       A  319   5.0
1       A  323   2.0
2       A  336   NaN
3       A  352   NaN
4       A  379   NaN
5       A  424   NaN
6       A  461   NaN
7       A  486   7.0
8       A  496   NaN
9       A  499   NaN
10      B  303   8.0
11      B  334   7.0
12      B  346  22.0
13      B  373   NaN
14      B  374  13.0
15      B  395   NaN
16      B  401   NaN
17      B  408   5.0
18      B  458  11.0
19      B  492   NaN
```

I want a new column showing the rolling sum of 'foo' every 30 days.

So far I've tried:

```
df['foo_30day'] = df.groupby('client').rolling(30, on='day', min_periods=1)['foo'].sum().values
```

But it looks like it's taking the rolling sum of the last 30 rows.

I was also thinking of maybe changing the 'day' column to a datetime format, then using `rolling('30D')` but I'm not sure how or even if that's the best approach. I've also tried to use a groupby reindex to stretch the 'day' column and doing a simple `rolling(30)` but it's not working for me.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the days to datetime then use `window='30D'`. The days will be converted to datetime, with a date starting from the first possible date in Pandas (1970-01-01).

You can optionally specify the starting date with an `origin` attribute in `to_datetime`, but for your example that wouldn't matter.

```
df = df.sort_values(["client", "day"]).reset_index(drop=True)

df["day_datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["day"], unit="D")

df["foo_30day"] = (
    df.groupby("client")
    .rolling("30D", on="day_datetime", min_periods=1)["foo"]
    .sum()
    .values
)
```

```
   client  day   foo day_datetime  foo_30day
0       A  319   5.0   1970-11-16        5.0
1       A  323   2.0   1970-11-20        7.0
2       A  336   NaN   1970-12-03        7.0
3       A  352   NaN   1970-12-19        2.0
4       A  379   NaN   1971-01-15        NaN
5       A  424   NaN   1971-03-01        NaN
6       A  461   NaN   1971-04-07        NaN
7       A  486   7.0   1971-05-02        7.0
8       A  496   NaN   1971-05-12        7.0
9       A  499   NaN   1971-05-15        7.0
10      B  303   8.0   1970-10-31        8.0
11      B  334   7.0   1970-12-01        7.0
12      B  346  22.0   1970-12-13       29.0
13      B  373   NaN   1971-01-09       22.0
14      B  374  13.0   1971-01-10       35.0
15      B  395   NaN   1971-01-31       13.0
16      B  401   NaN   1971-02-06       13.0
17      B  408   5.0   1971-02-13        5.0
18      B  458  11.0   1971-04-04       11.0
19      B  492   NaN   1971-05-08        NaN
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks like a solid start but the values are not correct.

Comment: @amance True, they're in the wrong order. SInce we're grouping by `'client'`, it needs to be included in the sort at the beginning: `["client", "day"]`. I've edited the answer, should be correct now